# How can I produce a Tag type for any datatype for use with DSum, without Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

**background**

I want to write some library code, which internally uses DSum to manipulate a user's datatype. DSum requires a 'tag' type that has a single type argument. However I want my code to work with just any old concrete type. So, I'd like to just take the user's type and automatically produce the tag type. I've asked a very similar question here [How can I programatically produce this datatype from the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582270/how-can-i-programatically-produce-this-datatype-from-the-other/40582869?noredirect=1#comment68402379_40582869), and gotten a great answer. That answer relies on TH, mainly so that it can create top-level declarations. However, I actually don't care about the top-level declaration, and I'd prefer to avoid the TH if possible.

**question**

[How] can I write, with some generic programming technique, a datatype

```
data Magic t a ...
```

where given some arbitrary sum type, e.g.

```
data SomeUserType = Foo Int | Bar Char | Baz Bool String
```

`Magic SomeUserType` is equivalent to this 'tag' type that can be used with DSum?

```
data TagSomeUserType a where
  TagFoo :: TagSomeUserType Int
  TagBar :: TagSomeUserType Char
  TagBaz :: TagSomeUserType (Bool, String)
```

Comment: "I actually don't care about the top-level declaration" - how do you intend to create a type without creating a declaration for it?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I guess they want a declaration of a type `Magic t a`, which somehow "digs" inside the definition of `t` and produces a type isomorphic to the associated `Tag...`. I don't think this is feasible without breaking parametric polymorphism: one would need some kind of reflection inside `t`'s definition.

Comment: basically as chi says - so, instead of saying `data TagSomeUserType a ...`, and giving the full definition, I'd like to be able to say `type TagSomeUserType a = Magic SomeUserType`

Comment: I suppose you could define `Magic` as a `data family` and then generate `data instance Magic SomeUserType where ...` but you'd still need Template Haskell for that

Comment: I'm afraid @BenjaminHodgson is right and you still need TH to make a type. Making a `data family` is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some here have claimed, it is perfectly sensible (and in fact quite straightforward, with the correct library - `generics-sop`) to define such a type. Essentially all the machinery is provided by this library already:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, PolyKinds, DeriveGeneric #-} 

import Generics.SOP 
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC 
import Data.Dependent.Sum

data Tup2List :: * -> [*] -> * where 
  Tup0 :: Tup2List () '[] 
  Tup1 :: Tup2List x '[ x ] 
  TupS :: Tup2List r (x ': xs) -> Tup2List (a, r) (a ': x ': xs) 

newtype GTag t i = GTag { unTag :: NS (Tup2List i) (Code t) }
```

The type `GTag` is what you call `Magic`. The actual 'magic' happens in the `Code` type family, which compute the generic representation of a type, as a list of lists of types. The type `NS (Tup2List i) xs` means that for precisely one of `xs`, `Tup2List i` holds - this is simply a proof that a list of arguments is isomorphic to some tuple.

All the classes you need can be derived:

```
data SomeUserType = Foo Int | Bar Char | Baz Bool String 
  deriving (GHC.Generic, Show) 
instance Generic SomeUserType
```

You can define some pattern synonyms for the tags valid for this type:

```
pattern TagFoo :: () => (x ~ Int) => GTag SomeUserType x 
pattern TagFoo = GTag (Z Tup1) 

pattern TagBar :: () => (x ~ Char) => GTag SomeUserType x 
pattern TagBar = GTag (S (Z Tup1)) 

pattern TagBaz :: () => (x ~ (Bool, String)) => GTag SomeUserType x 
pattern TagBaz = GTag (S (S (Z (TupS Tup1))))
```

and a simple test:

```
fun0 :: GTag SomeUserType i -> i -> String 
fun0 TagFoo i = replicate i 'a' 
fun0 TagBar c = c : [] 
fun0 TagBaz (b,s) = (if b then show else id) s 

fun0' = \(t :& v) -> fun0 t v 

main = mapM_ (putStrLn . fun0' . toTagVal) 
          [ Foo 10, Bar 'q', Baz True "hello", Baz False "world" ]
```

Since this is expressed in terms of a generic type function, you can write generic operations over tags. For example, `exists x . (GTag t x, x)` is isomorphic to `t` for any `Generic t`:

```
type GTagVal t = DSum (GTag t) I 

pattern (:&) :: forall (t :: * -> *). () => forall a. t a -> a -> DSum t I
pattern t :& a = t :=> I a     

toTagValG_Con :: NP I xs -> (forall i . Tup2List i xs -> i -> r) -> r 
toTagValG_Con Nil k = k Tup0 () 
toTagValG_Con (I x :* Nil) k = k Tup1 x
toTagValG_Con (I x :* y :* ys) k = toTagValG_Con (y :* ys) (\tp vl -> k (TupS tp) (x, vl))

toTagValG :: NS (NP I) xss -> (forall i . NS (Tup2List i) xss -> i -> r) -> r 
toTagValG (Z x) k = toTagValG_Con x (k . Z)
toTagValG (S q) k = toTagValG q (k . S)

fromTagValG_Con :: i -> Tup2List i xs -> NP I xs 
fromTagValG_Con i Tup0 = case i of { () -> Nil } 
fromTagValG_Con x Tup1 = I x :* Nil 
fromTagValG_Con xs (TupS tg) = I (fst xs) :* fromTagValG_Con (snd xs) tg 

toTagVal :: Generic a => a -> GTagVal a 
toTagVal a = toTagValG (unSOP $ from a) ((:&) . GTag)

fromTagVal :: Generic a => GTagVal a -> a 
fromTagVal (GTag tg :& vl) = to $ SOP $ hmap (fromTagValG_Con vl) tg
```

---

As for the need for `Tup2List`, it is needed for the simply reason that you represent a constructor of two arguments (`Baz Bool String`) as a tag over a tuple of `(Bool, String)` in your example.

You could also implement it as

```
type HList = NP I -- from generics-sop 

data Tup2List i xs where Tup2List :: Tup2List (HList xs) xs
```

which represents the arguments as a heterogeneous list, or even more simply

```
newtype GTag t i = GTag { unTag :: NS ((:~:) i) (Code t) }
type GTagVal t = DSum (GTag t) HList  

fun0 :: GTag SomeUserType i -> HList i -> String 
fun0 TagFoo (I i :* Nil) = replicate i 'a' 
fun0 ...
```

However, the tuple representation does have the advantage that unary tuples are 'projected' to the single value which is in the tuple (i.e., instead of `(x, ())`). If you represent arguements in the obvious way, functions such as `fun0` must pattern match to retrieve the single value stored in a constructor.

Comment: why do we need Tup2List?

Comment: @ajp See the edit. It is mainly just convenience and a choice of encoding (i.e. a design choice, which you are free to make how you want). I just wanted a fully faithful translation of the desired pseudocode.

Comment: where does (:&) come from? I don't see it on stackage hoogle https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.9/hoogle?q=%3A%26&exact=on (which does turn up e.g. (:=>)

Comment: actually, i've figured that out - (:&) should just be (:=>). However, I am stuck writing a GEq instance for GTag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698207/how-can-i-write-this-geq-instance

Comment: @ajp Actually it is the pattern synonym equal to `pattern t :& a = t :=> I a` - I added this code. (And I will take a look at this question, thank you ;))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can dispense with the TH since, as noted in the comments, you still need to make a type at the end of the day. As Benjamin notes, you are probably looking for a `data family`.

What you call `Magic`, I will refer to as `Tagged`.

Here is the adjusted code you will need for **tag.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Tag where

import Language.Haskell.TH

makeTag :: Name -> Name -> DecsQ
makeTag name tag = do
    -- Reify the data declaration to get the constructors.
    -- Note we are forcing there to be no type variables...
    (TyConI (DataD _ _ [] _ cons _)) <- reify name

    pure [ DataInstD [] tag [(ConT name), (VarT (mkName "a"))] Nothing (tagCon <$> cons) [] ]
  where
  -- Given a constructor, construct the corresponding constructor for
  -- Tag GADT
  tagCon :: Con -> Con
  tagCon (NormalC conName args) =
    let tys = fmap snd args
        tagType = foldl AppT (TupleT (length tys)) tys
    in GadtC [mkName ("Tag" ++ nameBase conName)] []
             (AppT (AppT (ConT tag) (ConT name)) tagType)
```

And, a sample use case (all the way through to something involving `DSum`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, GADTs, TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

import Data.Dependent.Sum
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Tag

-- Some data types
data SomeUserType1 = Foo Int | Bar String
data SomeUserType2 = Fooo Int | Baar Char | Baaz Bool String
data SomeAwkUserType = Foooo Int

-- Data family for all Tagged things
data family Tagged t a

-- Generated data family instances
makeTag ''SomeUserType1 ''Tagged
makeTag ''SomeUserType2 ''Tagged
makeTag ''SomeAwkUserType ''Tagged

--  A sample DSum's use case
toString :: DSum (Tagged SomeUserType1) Identity -> String
toString (TagFoo :=> Identity int) = show int
toString (TagBar :=> Identity str) = str
```

This ends up generating `data family` tag instances for each type. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks again alec. I'm still digesting this, but it is clearer that there's a fundamental need to generate code at some point. However, would it be possible to use the same tools that the Aeson library does (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:14)? The situation there seems pretty similar - take an arbitrary type and generate code that does need to interact with the structure of that type.

Comment: @ajp Unfortunately that isn't possible here. What they are doing is writing a default implementation that relies on the type having a `Generic` constraint satisfied. No code is generated though. Furthermore, we have to introduce new _types_, so `Generic` _really_ can't help us.

Comment: Also, `Generic` still works by code generation. When you say `deriving Generic` GHC writes an `instance` and fills in the type family `Rep`.