# How can I write function to convert generic type to Tag-shaped type for use with DSum?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

How can I implement this `toDSum` function? I've managed to get the base case to compile, but I don't know how to carry all the type information across a recursive call. Do I have to strip off the `Code` from the type before trying to recurse?

(this is a followup to [How can I write this GEq instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698207/how-can-i-write-this-geq-instance/40708395#40708395))

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Dependent.Sum
import Data.GADT.Compare
import Data.Proxy
import Generics.SOP
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC

type GTag t = GTag_ (Code t)
newtype GTag_ t (as :: [*]) = GTag (NS ((:~:) as) t)

instance GEq (GTag_ t) where
  geq (GTag (Z Refl)) (GTag (Z Refl)) = Just Refl
  geq (GTag (S x))    (GTag (S y))    = GTag x `geq` GTag y
  geq _               _               = Nothing

toDSum :: forall t . Generic t => t -> DSum (GTag t) (NP I)
toDSum = foo . unSOP . from
  where
    foo :: ()
        => NS (NP I) (Code t)
        -> DSum (GTag t) (NP I)
    foo = bar (Proxy :: Proxy t)

    bar :: forall t1 . ()
        => Proxy t1 -> NS (NP I) (Code t1)
        -> DSum (GTag t1) (NP I)
    bar _ (Z x) = GTag (Z Refl) :=> x
    bar _ (S x) = undefined
```

Comment: You're probably better off avoiding `Code` whenever possible. Does it matter, in context, that it's a code, or can you just leave it totally polymorphic?

Comment: I think it's necessary, because `GTag t` fits into `DSum`, but `GTag_ t` (which doesn't have `Code` added) doesn't. I might be wrong though. For full context, I'm working on this file https://github.com/anderspapitto/reflex-sumtype-render/blob/master/src/ReflexHelpers.hs, and this is the last missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version of this code was in my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593441/how-can-i-produce-a-tag-type-for-any-datatype-for-use-with-dsum-without-templat/40621740?noredirect=1#comment68627616_40621740) answer, but the types are slightly different, which actually simplifies the code.

As you have seen with `instance GEq (GTag_ t)`, when you want to write inductive functions on `NS` or `NP`, you need to keep the index parametric - you will see this general pattern quite a bit with 'dependant' programming (both real dependant programming and faking it in Haskell).

This is precisely the issue with `bar`:

```
forall t1 . () => Proxy t1 -> NS (NP I) (Code t1) -> DSum (GTag t1) (NP I)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no way for such a function to be recursive - simply because if `S rep :: NS (NP I) (Code t1)`, then it is not necessarily the case (indeed, it is never the case here) that `rep :: NS (NP I) (Code t2)` for some `t2` - and even if this fact *were* true, you would struggle to convince the compiler of it.

You must make this function (renaming to `toTagValG`) parametric in the index:

```
type GTagVal_ t = DSum (GTag_ t) (NP I)
type GTagVal t = DSum (GTag t) (NP I)

toTagValG :: NS f xss -> DSum (GTag_ xss) f 
toTagValG (Z rep) = GTag (Z Refl) :=> rep 
toTagValG (S rep) = case toTagValG rep of GTag tg :=> args -> GTag (S tg) :=> args
```

Then `xss` is instantiated with `Code t` when you use `to` or `from`, since `from :: a -> Rep a` and `Rep a = SOP I (Code a)`:

```
toTagVal :: Generic a => a -> GTagVal a
toTagVal = toTagValG . unSOP . from
```

Note this type is inferred (if you turn off the MonomorphismRestriction)

The other direction is even simpler:

```
fromTagVal :: Generic a => GTagVal a -> a 
fromTagVal = to . SOP . (\(GTag tg :=> args) -> hmap (\Refl -> args) tg)
```

Although you can write the function in the lambda with induction as well:

```
fromTagValG :: DSum (GTag_ xss) f -> NS f xss 
fromTagValG (GTag (Z Refl) :=> rep) = Z rep 
fromTagValG (GTag (S tg) :=> args) = S $ fromTagValG $ GTag tg :=> args
```

Note that you can assign a very general type to this function, and `toTagValG` - indeed, it does not mention `NP I` at all. You should also be able to convince yourself that these functions are each others inverses, and so witness an isomorphism between `NS f xss` and `DSum (GTag_ xss) f`.

Comment: thanks! though I'm just a little sad to see an answer after having painfully worked it out myself. I'll definitely read your commentary though

Answer (score 3):

although this is already answered, I'll add my own anyway since I spent several hours working it out.

short and sweet

```
toDSum :: Generic t => t -> DSum (GTag t) (NP I)
toDSum = foo (\f b -> GTag f :=> b) . unSOP . from
  where
    foo :: (forall a . (NS ((:~:) a) xs) -> NP I a -> r)
        -> NS (NP I) xs
        -> r
    foo k (Z x) =     (k . Z) Refl x
    foo k (S w) = foo (k . S)      w
```

Comment: Indeed, this function `foo` which I typically call `case_` basically says that `NS f xs` is the same as `exists x . (InList x xs, f x)` - since `NS ((:~:) a) xs` is an index into `xs` and a proof that `a` is the type at that index - this alternative encoding of `NS` allows you to write the function `mapNS :: (forall k . f k -> g k) -> NS f ks -> NS g ks` in constant time (instead of linear in the length of `ks`)!